# Paperclip S3 timestamp interpolation is one second off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm having a fair bit of trouble with a Rails app using `Paperclip` for attachments stored in `S3` and delivered with `Cloudfront`. I've configured `Paperclip` with timestamp interpolation. Everything works on a staging environment as expected. However, in production, the actual filename being stored uses a timestamp that is one second off. I have no idea why....

**Paperclip Configuration**

```
if configatron.aws.enabled
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
    access_key_id: configatron.aws.access_key,
    secret_access_key: configatron.aws.secret_key
  }
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:protocol] = 'https'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:bucket] = configatron.aws.bucket
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_alias] = configatron.aws.cloudfront_host
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_alias_url"

  # Change the default path
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "images/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style-:timestamp-:filename"
  Paperclip.interpolates(:timestamp) do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance_read(:updated_at).to_i 
  end
end
```

**Example record**

```
> alumni = Alumni.last
> alumni.updated_at.to_i
 => 1428719699
> alumni.thumb.url
 => "http://d2kektcjb0ajja.cloudfront.net/images/alumnis/thumbs/000/000/664/original-1428719699-diana-zeng-image.jpg?1428719699"
```

Notice that in the above `IRB` session, the `updated_at` timestamp matches the timestamp on the `filename`, which is correct. However, the file actually being stored in `S3` is `thumb-1428719698-diana-zeng-image.jpg`, notice that the timestamp is 1 second off! This means that the above URL is not found.

This only happens on Production. On our staging environment, it works perfectly. I have no idea why the above would happen.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Leonard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading Rails to >= 4.2.1.

The problem is that Rails 4.2.0 preserves fractional seconds, causing the drift to happen due to rounding to the nearest second.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1772